# How to add wasm support for Docker engine in headless mode

Tags: docker, webassembly

Since Oct 2022, Docker and WasmEdge have a beta feature on Docker Desktop to enable the support of WASM (via WasmEdge and containerd-wasmedge-slim).

Since I am running a Docker engine on a Linux VM, how do I try it without running a Docker desktop.
I found the following post online(https://github.com/chris-crone/wasm-day-na-22/tree/main/server), but I stucked in the middle when following the instruction.

Does anybody have some success stories to share?

Comment: Docker Desktop just has a build of Docker in it, and the WASM support shouldn't be specific to the Desktop build. Are you sure you can't get an edge Docker build and use that?

Comment: Hi tadman,
Thank you for your comment. I fully agree what you say and believe it is should be the way. From the official document it mentioned, a containerd image store is required which I didn't find a way to do that via docker cli.

Comment: You can create or open the daemon.json (/etc/docker/daemon.json) and add a json fragment "feature": { "containerd-snapshotter":true}, "experimental":true then do a docker info

Comment: Also the rumpl/moby github doesn't have a branch wasmedge so the checkout fails